# Enable CORS on ElementAPI

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I was wondering if there is way to enable CORS for the ElementAPI plugin? I want to be able to call the API from the website and not allow external client to access the API

Answer (score 1):

Not really anything to do with Craft or the ElementAPI plugin, but you can enable CORS at the Apache/.htaccess level [easy enough](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html).